# How to find the start pixel in an image using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

The image below shows the result after detecting the edge using sobel. It has two boundaries. I need to trace both of them. How do you find both the start pixels of both the boundaries and do the tracing?

An example is given below. It consists of 2 boundaries

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where is the start pixel of a circle?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are interested in [`bwboundaries`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html):

```
B = bwboundaries( BW );
```